# What does an uncaught products in collection error mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, next.js, shopify, shopify-storefront-api

I have a next.js website that get's products from Shopify. It was working well until a couple of months ago when the site stopped building on the development server.

When I run the website locally I now get a Cannot read properties of undefined error and the page doesn't load.

What are likely causes of the issue and how do I go about fixing it?

```
error - lib/shopify.js (353:31) @ getProductsInCollection
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collectionByHandle')
  351 |       const cursor = response.data.products.edges[num - 1].cursor;
  352 | 
> 353 |       return data.concat(await recursiveCatalog(cursor));
      |                               ^
  354 |     } else {
  355 |       return data;
  356 |     }
```

This is how I get the data from Shopify

```
    const domain = process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN
    const storefrontAccessToken = process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESSTOKEN
    
    async function ShopifyData(query) {
      const URL = `https://${domain}/api/2021-07/graphql.json`
    
      const options = {
        endpoint: URL,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": storefrontAccessToken,
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query })
      }
    
      try {
        const data = await fetch(URL, options).then(response => {
          return response.json()
        })
    
        return data
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Products not fetched")
      }
    }
```

The error seems to occur when I get products from a collection.

```
export async function getProductsInCollection() {
  const query = `
  {
    collectionByHandle(handle: "frontpage") {
      title
      products(first: 60) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
            productType
            handle
            metafields(first: 2) {
              edges {
                  node {
                      namespace
                      key
                      value
                  }
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`
  const response = await ShopifyData(query);
  const allProducts = response.data.collectionByHandle.products.edges
    ? response.data.collectionByHandle.products.edges
    : [];
  return allProducts;
}
```

```
export async function recursiveCatalog(cursor = '', initialRequest = true) {
  let data;

  if (cursor !== '') {
    const query = `{
      products(after: "${cursor}", first: 250) {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            id
            handle
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }`;

    const response = await ShopifyData(query);
    data = response.data.products.edges ? response.data.products.edges : [];

    if (response.data.products.pageInfo.hasNextPage) {
      const num = response.data.products.edges.length;
      const cursor = response.data.products.edges[num - 1].cursor;
      console.log('Cursor: ', cursor);

      return data.concat(await recursiveCatalog(cursor));
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  } else {
    const query = `{
      products(first: 250) {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            id
            handle
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
    }
    `;

    const response = await ShopifyData(query);
    data = response.data.products.edges ? response.data.products.edges : [];

    if (response.data.products.pageInfo.hasNextPage) {
      const num = response.data.products.edges.length;
      const cursor = response.data.products.edges[num - 1].cursor;

      return data.concat(await recursiveCatalog(cursor));
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `response.data` is undefined. Check what `response` contains!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `collectionByHandle` is deprecated and replaced with `collection`.

Add a guard to the response where you have used fetch API or Shopify API.

```js
    if (!response.ok) { 
        console.error('Error on fetching data') 
    }
```

This will be little help to understand that actually data are fetching.